# How to distinguish 2 variables on ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I was making 2 plots on ggplot, but now that I have succeed to do what I want, I would like to fuse this graph in one.
My problem is that my values and confidence intervals for each of my variables were obtained with a bootstrap. My data.frame that I use for each of my plot look like this :

[image: my first data frame]
[image: my second data frame]

As you can see, I have one column for my different treatments (pqual), V1 is my median, and lower and upper are my values for my confidence interval.

My script for my plot look like this :

```
Q10dplot <- ggplot(data=Q10d, aes(x=pqual, y=V1, col=pqual))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=lower, ymax=upper), width=.2)+
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0.5,2), breaks = c(0.5,1,1.5,2))+
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("scst" = "aquamarine3",
                               "svar" = "aquamarine4",
                               "ycst" = "darkgoldenrod3",
                               "yvar" = "darkgoldenrod4"))+
  theme_minimal()+
  ggtitle("Q10 d")+
  xlab("pqual") + ylab("Q10")+
  theme_grey(base_size = 22)
Q10dplot
```

I would like to put everything in one plot, but I don't know how.

Here is my data :

```
d1 <- structure(list(pqual = c("scst", "svar", "ycst", "yvar"), V1 = c(1.57018534500418, 
0.813141641335401, 1.83263172676745, 1.08637937362865), lower = c(1.46430733516951, 
0.754261886214852, 1.83263172676745, 1.04296652726617), median = c(1.56519136055835, 
0.813147324264586, 1.83263172676745, 1.08589629982024), upper = c(1.684225201556, 
0.875420698794502, 1.83263172676745, 1.12960240657212)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("bootscstd", 
"bootsvard", "bootycstd", "bootyvard"))

d2 <- structure(list(pqual = c("scst", "svar", "ycst", "yvar"), V1 = c(1.52392776239251, 
0.795105955855431, 1.7049070356902, 0.866155843608828), lower = c(1.42095510456812, 
0.740169509961879, 1.67591486183307, 0.831244001139425), median = c(1.52198888072917, 
0.794298998427312, 1.70461432040644, 0.864517118120389), upper = c(1.63130199180125, 
0.85303654089534, 1.73294982674048, 0.908100088043788)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("bootscst", 
"bootsvar", "bootycst", "bootyvar"))
```

To be more clear, my plot look like this :

[image: first plot]
[image: second plot]

and I would like to do this :

[image: plot wanted]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Row bind dataframes, then plot:

```
d <- data.table::rbindlist(list(d1 = d1, d2 = d2), idcol = "data")

ggplot(data=d, aes(x = pqual, y = V1, shape = data,
                   ymin = lower, ymax = upper, color = pqual))+
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(0.5))+
  geom_errorbar(width = 0.2, position = position_dodge(0.5))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I had started merging my data frames but it wasn't working. But with your code it corks. Thank you a lot.